# Can't figure out how to use cmd correctly to execute script in docker

Tags: docker, cmd, dockerfile

I am trying to figure out how to get the CMD command in dockerfile to run a script on startup for `docker run` I know that using the RUN command will get the image to prerun that script when building the image but I want it to run the script everytime I run a new container using that image. The script is just a simple script that outputs the current date/time to a file.

Here is the dockerfile that works if I use RUN

```
# Pull base image
FROM alpine:latest
# gcr.io/dev-ihm-analytics-platform/practice_docker:ulta
WORKDIR /root/
RUN apk --update upgrade && apk add bash
ADD ./script.sh ./
RUN ./script.sh
```

Here is the same dockerfile that doesnt work with CMD

```
# Pull base image
FROM alpine:latest
# gcr.io/dev-ihm-analytics-platform/practice_docker:ulta
WORKDIR /root/
RUN apk --update upgrade && apk add bash
ADD ./script.sh ./
CMD ["./script.sh"]
```

I have tried all sorts of things after the CMD command like ["/script.sh"], ["bash script.sh"], ["bash", "./script.sh"], bash script.sh but I always get an error and I don't know what I am doing wrong. All I want is to

docker run -it name_of_container bash

and then find that the script has executed be seeing there is an output file with the run information in the container once I am inside

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Try changing the `CMD` to an `ENTRYPOINT`. Also, it would probably be helpful to provide the error message.

Comment: That is the thing, I don't get any error messages when building the images. They build successfully but its obvious the script is never run because the file isn't there so I run it manually in the container and it executes. Also if I change the CMD to ENTRYPOINT how do I open the container to view the contents and verify that the script executed since running "docker run -it --name test image_name bash" would interfere with ENTRYPOINT command?

Answer (score 2):

There’s three basic ways to do this:

1. You can `RUN ./script.sh`.  It will happen once, at `docker build` time, and be baked into your image.
2. You can `CMD ./script.sh`.  It will happen once, and be the single command the container runs.  If you provide some alternate command (`docker run ... bash` for instance) that runs *instead of* this CMD.
3. You can write a custom entrypoint script that does this first-time setup, then runs the CMD or whatever got passed on the command line.  The main container process is the entrypoint, and it gets passed the command as arguments.  This script (and whatever it does inside) will get run on every startup.  This script can look something like

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   ./script.sh
   exec "$@"
   ```

   It needs to be separately COPYd into the image, and then you’d set something like `ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]`.

(Given the problem as you’ve actually described it — you have a shell script and you want to run it and inspect the file output in an interactive shell — I’d just run it at your local command prompt and not involve Docker at all.  This avoids all of these sequencing and filesystem mapping issues.)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want, but your first attempt, with the `RUN ./script.sh` line is probably the best.

The CMD and ENTRYPOINT commands are overridable on the command-line as flags to the `container run` command. So, if you want to ensure that this is run every time you start the container, then it shouldn't be part of the CMD or ENTRYPOINT commands.

Comment: Hmm the issue is that I am using google-composer kubernetes pod operator which needs asks for an image and a cmd to run on that image which means I need to figure out how to use cmd correctly so that I can call the pod operator with my image and the command I need to run it:

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py

So for this purpose RUN wont work for me

Answer (score -1):

Well, iam using the CMD command to start my Java applications and when the container is inside the WORKDIR iam executing the following:

```
CMD ["/usr/bin/java", "-jar", "-Dspring.profiles.active=default", "/app.jar"]
```

Have you tried to remove the "." in the CMD command so it looks like that:

```
CMD ["/script.sh"]
```

There might be a different syntax when using RUN or CMD.